# Strategic voting on A51 proposed questions

Tags: discussion, voting, area-51, strategy

This is a situation that's very common:

[image]

People viewing the proposal are asked to vote up other questions to advance the proposal, i.e. to vote strategically. I don't know about the feeling in general but strategic voting is a bad thing.

People who choose to follow the proposal probably want it to succeed and so will aim to make their votes count as much as possible rather than voting for their favourite questions. Likewise someone aiming to hijack the proposal can strategically *downvote* a bunch of questions with a score of 10.

There are a few simpler fixes:

- Hide vote counts entirely, and randomize the order of questions. People are forced to manually find and upvote good questions.
- Make a moderation decision to kill these comments. It wouldn't fix the problem entirely, but could go a fair way.
- Just randomize the order of questions. Currently these comments tend to appear on the top question(s) only.
- Increase the number of votes allowed.

The system could be changed in more complex ways too, that change the requirements for upvoted questions, or automatically detecting strategic voting (in the same way serial votes are detected?). I think this is something that should be addressed at some level though.

Comment: Area 51 has it's own meta area: http://discuss.area51.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/area51-meta. I am fairly sure this topic has already been discussed there.

Comment: Related: [Comments saying “please do not upvote this question”](http://discuss.area51.stackexchange.com/q/9720) and [How to deal with users urging not to vote on give question any more?](http://discuss.area51.stackexchange.com/q/8632).

Comment: @MartijnPieters I looked for a meta site but couldn't find one. Meta is a tag now?

Comment: Area51 is 'special', like Meta.stackoverflow.com; it is relatively 'old' in Stack Exchange terms. On Area51, meta is a tag.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Ok my bad.

Comment: NP, it *is* confusing.

Comment: http://discuss.area51.stackexchange.com/questions/8632/how-to-deal-with-users-urging-not-to-vote-on-give-question-any-more and http://discuss.area51.stackexchange.com/questions/10185/staging-criteria-encourage-bad-voting-behavior